# Как по повторному клику удалять сообщение?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Создал глобальный event bus. С одного компонента я передаю сообщение:

```
export default{
        data: ()=>({
            background: 'background__dark'
        }),
        methods:{
            backgroundChange(){
                bus.$emit('background', this.background);
            }
        }
    }
```

И в другом компоненте я его принимаю:

```
export default{
        data: ()=>({
            background: ''
        }),
        created(){
            bus.$on('background', data =>{
               this.background = data
            })
        }
    }
```

Но этот event Работает в одну сторону, как при повторном клике убирать это сообщение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('changer', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      bgClass: 'bgShow_class',
      isShow: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change () {
      bus.$emit('change', this.isShow, this.bgClass);
      this.isShow = !this.isShow; // Меняем состояние в компоненте и передаём его
    }
  },
  template: '<button @click="change">Changes the bg in the parent instance.</button>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    bgClass: ''
  },
  created () {
    bus.$on('change', (isShow, bgClass) => {
      this.bgClass = isShow ? bgClass : '';
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.bgShow_class {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <div :class="bgClass">
    Hello, world!
  </div>
  
  <changer></changer>
</div>
```